# Why does an Avro field that was string now require avro.java.string type?

Tags: java, avro, confluent-platform, avro-tools

In Avro IDL I have a Message record defined as follows:

```
record Message{

    MessageId id;
    array<string> dataField;
}
```

I am using this record in another record with a null union:

```
record Invoice{
    ...
    union {null,array<Message>} message;
}
```

We have a Java Kafka consumer (we're using Confluent Platform) that is using the `avro-maven-plugin` version 1.10.2, configured with `<stringType>String</stringType>`

When we are making a call such as this:

```
List<String> msgList = message.getDataField();
for (String msg : msgList) {...}
```

we receive the following error on the second line: `class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to class java.lang.String`

Previously, the Invoice object was defined as:

```
 record Invoice{
    ...
    array<Message> message;
}
```

and we did not receive this error. We have found that in our schema file, changing from

```
 "name" : "dataField",
      "type" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "items" : "string"
      }
```

to

```
"name" : "dataField",
 "type" : {
   "type" : "array",
     "items" :{
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string" : "String"
   }
 }
```

corrects the problem.

I'm unclear as to why adding the union caused this change in behavior. Should I declare all of the strings in the schema with the `avro.java.string` and if so, how do I do that with Avro IDL?

Comment: I did find [an open Avro bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2838) which appears to be related to this.

Comment: I've created an ASF [JIRA bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-3217) related to the inability to create `avro.java.string` entries via Avro IDL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, there appears to be a couple of ways to resolve this, at least when using the Confluent Platform, version 5.5.1 or later. And I'm considering the problem to be an [open defect](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2838) with Avro.

The first option is to update the Avro Schema file with a global search and replace of `"type":"string"` to

```
"type": {
       "avro.java.string": "String",
       "type": "string"
    }
```

This first option would need to be done after creating any files via Avro IDL since it doesn't support this construct, making IDL less useful in this case. Strangely, this approach does not appear to impact records that come in via REST Proxy that have `"type":"string"` associated without the additional `avro.java.string` information. They appear able to use a schema defined in either way; I was expecting the updated schema with the `avro.java.string` information to cause problems with REST Proxy requests that don't have that detail.

The second option is to set `auto.register.schemas=false` and `use.latest.version=true`, though this may cause unintended consequences with compatibility in the future.

The third option is to just not use the `<stringType>` directive in the Maven configuration for Avro Tools. This means a lot of coding around the `CharacterSequence` that is used by default, usually in the form of `.toString()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

We can avoid changes in actual schema by setting property `avro.remove.java.properties=true`

This will put avro.java.string in generated POJO but it will ignore same while connecting to schema registry, and will not throw error to re-register new schema. So we will not require any change in avro schema file or in POJO after this.

It is mentioned here in this document https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html#avro-serializer